# How to make UIScrollView not so sensitive to pinch

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uigesturerecognizer

I have a UIScrollView with zooming enabled. This zooming enabled scroll view is inside another UIScrollView. The outer scroll view should receive the two fingers pan/swipe to switch pages. Here is my problem, the UIScrollView can treat the two fingers pan/swipe as on finger, but if the inner scroll view enabled zooming, the pinch gesture recognizer in the inner scroll view will be very sensitive. Any tiny two fingers movement will be interpreted as a pinch gesture and it prevents the outer scroll view to receive two fingers pan. Is it possible to change the sensitivity of the pinch in UIScrollView.

I did see there is a @package variable called _scaleThreshold in UIPinchGestureRecognizer, but it is package variable and can't be accessed outside. It is impossible for me to change it.

I'm wondering whether there is a way to make the threshold larger for the pinch gesture in UIScrollView.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set the scale and the velocity props of UIPinchGestureRecognizer, one of them maybe right for what you want.

**EDIT:** Or you could call the requireGestureRecognizerToFail:recognizerYouDontWantInterfering merhod on whatever gesture you want to take effect.

Comment: Actually, I want the UIPinchGestureRecognizer ignore little pinch and let other gesture recognizers to take charge of the touches. Set scale and velocity doesn't help.